# Removing duplicates from cart items array and adding quantity

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that contains product items, in some cases, the product is added to the cart twice and I would like to remove the duplicates and add the quantities together

The items need to be matched by `id`

What's the best way I can fix this?

An example array is:

```
Array
        (

        [0] => Array
            (
                [type] => fabrication
                [id] => 886
                [price] => 11.00
                [quantity] => 1
                [producttitle] => Edge Profiles - Edge Profile B - Single 5mm Radius
                [index] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [type] => fabrication
                [id] => 887
                [price] => 11.00
                [quantity] => 1
                [producttitle] => Edge Profiles - Edge Profile C - Single 19mm Radius
                [index] => 3
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [type] => fabrication
                [id] => 887
                [price] => 11.00
                [quantity] => 10
                [producttitle] => Edge Profiles - Edge Profile C - Single 19mm Radius
                [index] => 4
            )

    )
```

This should become:

```
Array
    (

        [0] => Array
            (
                [type] => fabrication
                [id] => 886
                [price] => 11.00
                [quantity] => 1
                [producttitle] => Edge Profiles - Edge Profile B - Single 5mm Radius
                [index] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [type] => fabrication
                [id] => 887
                [price] => 11.00
                [quantity] => 11
                [producttitle] => Edge Profiles - Edge Profile C - Single 19mm Radius
                [index] => 3
            )

    )
```

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: It did. Thanks a bunch, bud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (untested):

```
$cleanArray = array();
foreach($array AS $item) {
    if($cleanArray[$item['id']]) {
        $cleanArray[$item['id']]['quantity'] += $item['quantity'];
    } else {
        $cleanArray[$item['id']] = $item;
    }
}
```

Note your new array will be indexed by item ID, which will actually help you out a lot. Do that initially, and it's much easier to check for existing cart items rather than allowing duplicates in the first place.

If you really don't like having `$cleanArray` indexed by ID, you can get rid of those after your duplicate cleanup:

```
$cleanArray = array_values($cleanArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new array to check and combine the results:

$check = array();

then loop over your existing array and use the id as the array key of your check array;

```
foreach(array as $whatever){  
  if(isset($check[$whatever['id']])){  
    $check[$whatever['id']]['quantity'] += $whatever['quantity'];  
  } else {  
    $check[$whatever['id']] = $whatever;  
  }  
}
```

now you should have an array $check to replace the original array with combined results.

oh looks like jszobody beat me to it :)